# How do we show hubtile without animation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to show two fields in single tile in windows phone 7 application.
1)name
2)description
Like a static image,tile should display name and description

For displaying them,I dont want any animation effects in tiles.
Is there way of disabling the animation effects as its ruining the application experience.
I am using Toolkit :hubtile in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using the HubTileService class. Say you got the following Tile in XAML:

```
<toolkit:HubTile Name="myTile" Title="Tile 1" GroupTag="tileGroup" />
```

Now you can either freeze just this tile using:

```
HubTileService.FreezeHubTile(myTile);
```

or if you have several tiles with same GroupTag you can freeze them all at once with:

```
HubTileService.FreezeGroup("tileGroup");
```

To start animation again you can use:

```
HubTileService.UnfreezeTile(myTile);
HubTileService.UnfreezeGroup("tileGroup");
```

If you want to Control which animation part (Visual state) you want visible, for example the flipped state might be what you want, then you change that using the Visual state manager like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(myTile, "Flipped", true);
```

For a more in depth explaination of the HubTile there is a [good guide at Windows Phone Geek](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-hubtile-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api).